# Allowing computers in network view sites in my web server

Tags: networking, apache-http-server

I'm running a LAMP on my ubuntu 13.10 machine and I have some site running on it(personal projects). Now I want the guys in our network to be able to type my ip/site and view what Ive been working on. I have set up virtual hosts on my server to run this site. At the moment if I connect my cell to the network and type my ip I see the default apache "It works" but if I do ip/site I get a not found. I not much of a system guy so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Is your actual question, "how can machines connect to my web server on its outside IP address from inside my LAN?"

Answer (score 0):

If you open LAMP, and get the start/stop servers screen, go to Preferences and under Apache you can set the `Document Root` to the root directory of your website.

If you can't get to that, you might not be able to, I can only compare with MAMP on my Mac, then you need to find the httpd.conf file for the Apache server, and find a line starting with `DocumentRoot`, you can change the current path to your website root directory.